# How do we render a view in new page in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have been working on an angular 2 project and I am not clear as in how to make a route open new view instead of the same page. All I can do is render in the same view but I want the route to open a completely new view.

Comment: This might be the way you configure the route. Can you elaborate more about your requirement/question?

Comment: What is a "new view"? If you mean a new tab or new window, then this won't work. Angular2 is for SPA and if you want to open another tab or window this is a new and different application. The router doesn't support that. You can use a `<a href="..." target="_blank">` to get something opened in a new tab.

Comment: Assume that i don't have a "nav" and i want all my routes to load a new layout in complete page. Now if i use routerlink and router-outlet it always loads the template into it but the old template still exists.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer we had ng-view in angular 1 and all the templates associated with the routes loads into this. But in agular2 how do i achieve this?

Comment: That's the default behavior. You can't get rid of the root component (`AppComponent`) though, but if it is a component that only contains a `<router-outlet>` then you get exactly what you want. If you don't please post your code (route config, router initialization, components with selectors and template content (where the `<router-outlet>`s are.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer  for immediate response. I have uploaded the code on to github. please have a look at it.
https://github.com/reddysridhar53/angular2-test

When we click on start now it has to render click me and the previous template should go away.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your root component ( the AppComponent most probably) contains the 
    < router-outlet > only. Then it is just a matter of configuring your routing configuration. Make your default route to another component, i.e
    `const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MyComponent },
      { path: 'another', component: AnotherComponent }
    ];`

and not the AppComponent.

Here's a plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/CvztzcejGvXogmx0kmjL?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem @sridharreddy . Mark this as a solution so that others can see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate module and separate routing for the particular view and you can also use ChildComponent as an Optional routing